# Deserialize Kafka-Avro-Message received from AWS Lambda Trigger

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-lambda

We have set up a Kafka Lambda Trigger in AWS to consume from a Kafka read API. The connection was successful and I can receive Json Objects in my C# Lambda function. However, the Json Objects contain a value property with the serialised data and I'm struggeling to deserialise it using our AVRO schema. I'm using the nugget packages Confluent.Kafka and Confluent.SchemaRegistry.Serdes.
This is my attempt:

```
var value = myRecord.GetProperty("value").GetBytesFromBase64();

var schemaRegistryConfig = new SchemaRegistryConfig
{
    Url = "mySchemaRegistry"

};

using var schemaRegistry = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(schemaRegistryConfig);

var deserializer = new AvroDeserializer<MyAvroGeneratedClass>(schemaRegistry);
try
{
    var result = deserializer.DeserializeAsync(value, false, SerializationContext.Empty).Result;
    return result;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    return null;
}
```

Currently, DeserializeAsync throws the following Exception:

```
AvroDeserializer only accepts type parameters of int, bool, double, string, float, long, byte[], instances of ISpecificRecord and subclasses of SpecificFixed.
```

Does someone has experience with a similar setup and can guide me how this can work?

I've tried to use other types than byte[], but this will not work with the AvroDeserializer class.